# how to rollback a branch merge in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

[image]I have merged my development branch with production by mistake. I haven't made it public, please let me know how can I revert back this merge ? 
I am using TortoiseHG workbench.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just strip the commit that did the merge, assuming it's the last one.  Right-click, Modify History -> Strip.

If it's more complex that that, post more detail (e.g. screenshot of the graph) and I'll try to help.

Comment: I have added the snapshot please check, sprint_july should not be merge with hydrant_prod, I have to revert that merge.

Comment: Update to the last "sprint_july", then strip the "Merge with sprint_july" commit, you should be fine.